# I can't send a variable for more then one fragment (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have to pass the value of a variable of my first fragment to my third fragment, however, the method I am using only goes to the second fragment. Does anyone know how I could pass the value of the variable for my third fragment ??

My first Fragment:

```
package com.example.android.dungeonsanddragons;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class Fragmente_Ficha_Parte01 extends Fragment {
    OnInformaçõesSetListener onInformaçõesSetListener;

@Nullable
@Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup    container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmente_ficha_parte01, container, false);
       return view;
   }

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ...
        ...
        onInformaçõesSetListener.setInformações(Classe, Experiencia);

    }

    public interface OnInformaçõesSetListener {
        void setInformações(String classe, String experiencia);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            onInformaçõesSetListener = (OnInformaçõesSetListener) activity;
        }   catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

My MainActivity:

```
package com.example.android.dungeonsanddragons;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragmente_Ficha_Parte01.OnInformaçõesSetListener {
   ...
   ...
@Override
    public void setInformações(String classe, String experiencia) {

        List<Fragment> allFragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        for (Fragment fragmento : allFragments) {
            if (fragmento instanceof Fragmente_Ficha_Parte02) {
                ((Fragmente_Ficha_Parte02) fragmento).updateInfo(classe, experiencia);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My second Fragment:

```
package com.example.android.dungeonsanddragons;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragmente_Ficha_Parte02 extends Fragment {
    String TextClasse = "", ExperienciaString;
    int Experiencia = 0, cont = 5;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmente_ficha_parte02, container, false);

    return view;
}

public void updateInfo(String classe, String experiencia) {
    TextClasse = classe;
    if (experiencia == null || experiencia.equals("")) {
        Experiencia = 0;
    } else {
        ExperienciaString = experiencia;
        Experiencia = Integer.valueOf(experiencia);
    }
    onResume();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
...
...
}
```

My third Fragment:

```
package com.example.android.dungeonsanddragons;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragmente_Ficha_Parte03 extends Fragment {
   String TextClasse = "";
    int Experiencia = 0;

    @Nullable
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmente_ficha_parte03, container, false);

    return view;
}
public void updateInfo(String classe, String experiencia) {
    TextClasse = classe;
    if (experiencia == null || experiencia.equals("")) {
        Experiencia = 0;
    } else {
        Experiencia = Integer.valueOf(experiencia);
    }
    onResume();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

   final  TextView TextHabilidadeConjuração = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.habilidadeConjuração);

    if(TextClasse != null){
        if(TextClasse.equals("Monge")){
            TextHabilidadeConjuração.setText("Monge");
        }
    }
}
```

}

In the main activity, the "List allFragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();" always stays with size of 2, and i don't know how fix this

Comment: May need to post your third fragment, is the third fragment of class Fragmente_Ficha_Parte02? Since your activity checks for if (fragmento instanceof Fragmente_Ficha_Parte02) but not Fragmente_Ficha_Parte03

Comment: It makes no difference put the "Fragmente_Ficha_Parte03" instead of "Fragmente_Ficha_Parte02" because it only goes up to the second fragment, that's the problem. And no, "Fragmente_Ficha_Parte03" is not part of the class "Fragmente_Ficha_Parte02"

Comment: I mean, the size == 2 sounds right if you're adding 3 fragments. Your variable isn't being passed to the third fragment though because you're only checking if the fragment is an instanceof Fragmente_Ficha_Parte02 which will catch the second fragment but not the third, which is an instanceof Fragmente_Ficha_Parte03.

Comment: allFragments = {ArrayList@831563404992}  size = 2
 0 = {Fragmente_Ficha_Parte01@831563396400} "Fragmente_Ficha_Parte01{9d0a7530 #0 id=0x7f0d0070 android:switcher:2131558512:0}"
 1 = {Fragmente_Ficha_Parte02@831563404360} "Fragmente_Ficha_Parte02{9d0a9448 #1 id=0x7f0d0070 android:switcher:2131558512:1}"

Comment: excuse the code be all unorganized, could not organize, but that's my problem, within the variable "allfragments" only has two fragments, the first and the second, the third is even listed, so I can not send the value of variable for the third fragment. Is there any way to fix this?